# How to force mysql to show schema name along with column names in a query?

Tags: mysql, delphi, mariadb

I need to join 3 tables which have some columns with same name, like *id* and some foreign keys columns.

I make a select query and the results come with table names only. How to get results like "dbname"."columnname" in my queries so I can identify from which table is each columns without having to specify every columns in the query (using only an *)?

Note: I use Delphi with ZeosLib, so a solution using these tools would be OK as well. But I prefer to set this in the data base.

Comment: A little bit of investigation will reveal a large number of reasons to avoid use of `SELECT *` for anything other than ad-hoc investigative queries. Most importantly, they're a serious performance killer in a bunch of obvious and even a few very subtle ways. But over and above that, the few minutes you save now by lazily using `SELECT *` means that future maintenance is hampered trying to decipher exactly what data the statement is intended to return. Stubbornly insisting you wish to find a "solution" that uses a well known bad-practice is probably not a good idea. ;)

Comment: As a side note, something that returns `TableName.ColumnName` won't be useful in some case. Consider self-joins e.g.: `SELECT e.EmpId, e.Name, m.Name AS ManagerName FROM Employees e LEFT OUTER JOIN Employees m ON m.EmpId = e.ManagerId`. So I strongly recommend instead of looking for a silver-bullet bad idea: Simply list columns explicitly and alias them appropriately.

Comment: Stop writing your queries with `SELECT *`, and you don't have any issues. There are no reasons to use `SELECT *` other than to make your code more difficult to maintain in the future and extreme laziness.  If you specify the table and column, you can alias as needed to determine which table the column came from, and you don't have to waste time asking questions like this one. The only reason to use `SELECT *` is if you don't know the name of the columns in the DB, in which case you can't be doing a JOIN.

Comment: The correct answer to this question will be the major weapon to work with someone else's badly written SQL :( There are no upvotes but downvotes for the question. +1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to create an alias for your field name in your query

```
 SELECT a.ID, b.ID
 FROM a
 JOIN b
```

You need doblue quote `"` for field names with special characters, so change it to.

```
 SELECT a.ID "a.ID", b.ID "b.ID"
```

OR

```
 SELECT a.ID "MeaningfullName", b.ID "OtherName"
```

For example here I have two fields name `"sent_dt"` and change one to `previous_time`

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b09bc/7)**

Comment: Just said in the question that I did not wanted to do that.

Comment: You could make your question more clear. And just because you dont want it doesnt mean you will have it. Unless you want create a dinamic sql?